# how to pass variables from controller to controller in prestashop?

Tags: php, controller, prestashop

is there a way to pass variables from a controller to another in prestashop? I'm tring to pass the new_address variable on an AddressController override like this:

```
Tools::redirect('index.php?controller='.$back.($mod ? '&back='.$mod : '') . '&new_address=' . $address->id);
```

NOTE that this is the original line + `. '&new_address=' . $address->id`, so I have to stick to `Tools::redirect`.

By using that line, no new_address is found on the next page in $_GET. From OrderController and ParentOrderController too, I don't see it.

Comment: Are you sure [this](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/controllers/front/AddressController.php#L243) line is executing? If it is then probably something is doing another redirection in the middle.

Comment: Yes I'm sure it's executed, and I've found the reason of failure in Tool::redirect, I'm coding an override then I'll post an official answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the reason in Tools::redirect. It has a line like this:

```
$url = Tools::strReplaceFirst('&', '?', $url);
```

here they are basically excluding any queryvar other than the first one, so you won't find any if you add some. If you have `index.php?a=1&b=2`, you'll get `index.php?a=1?b=2`. I don't really see the point... Maybe it's a bug.

So I overridden Tools::redirect like this (modded lines are commented):

```
public static function redirect($url, $base_uri = __PS_BASE_URI__, Link $link = null, $headers = null){
  if (!$link) $link = Context::getContext()->link;

  $querystring = array_pop(explode('?', $url)); // MOD: Save the original querystring. I take the last item in array because sometimes (i think it's a bug) the $url is like index.php?controller=order.php?step=1, so 2 question marks.

  if (strpos($url, 'http://') === false && strpos($url, 'https://') === false && $link) {
    if (strpos($url, $base_uri) === 0) {
      $url = substr($url, strlen($base_uri));
    }
    if (strpos($url, 'index.php?controller=') !== false && strpos($url, 'index.php/') == 0) {
      $url = substr($url, strlen('index.php?controller='));
      if (Configuration::get('PS_REWRITING_SETTINGS')) {
        $url = Tools::strReplaceFirst('&', '?', $url); // ...Don't see the point here...
      }
    }

    $explode = explode('?', $url);

    // don't use ssl if url is home page
    // used when logout for example
    $use_ssl = !empty($url);
    $url = $link->getPageLink($explode[0], $use_ssl);

    if($querystring) $url .= '?'.$querystring; // MOD: adding full querystring!! Also deleted 3 lines that added $explode[1] instead
  }

  // Send additional headers
  if ($headers) {
    if (!is_array($headers)) $headers = array($headers);

    foreach ($headers as $header) {
      header($header);
    }
  }

  header('Location: '.$url);
  exit;
}
```